# Ruby, метод split cтранные аргументы с вопросительным знаком

Tags: ruby, split

**Необязательная инфа:**

Уже как полторы недели занимаюсь изучением языка программирования Ruby. В качестве небольшоей практики решаю задачи на "CodeWars", и в качестве доп. задания рассмастриваю чужие варианты решения задачи, так вот попалось странное решение (возможно для меня), не могу разобраться с агрументами передаваемыми в  метод split.

**Основаная часть**

Проблема: Непонимамние передаваемых аргументов.

Задача: "https://www.codewars.com/kata/meeting/train/ruby"

Автор решения "hrrs01"

Код:

```
def meeting(s)
    names = s.upcase.split ?;
    names.map!{|x|y=x.split(?:); [y[1],y[0]]}
    names.sort.map{|x|"(#{x[0]}, #{x[1]})"}*''
end
```

**Вопрос**: Что в данном случае обозначает вопросительный знак? Является ли верным следующие выражение ?

```
split(";") == split ?;
```

В документации https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-split ответа не нашёл или плохо перевёл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нотация `?x` означает то же, что `"x"`. Это просто странный способ сделать строку из одного символа. В вашем случае `?;` — это `";"`, а `?:` — это `":"`. Так писать никогда не следует.

В руби до версии 1.9 эта нотация возвращала код символа, но потом это убрали, чтобы сделать язык более удобным. Чтобы не ломать совместимость совсем, нотацию оставили, но «подправили».

См. также вот этот вопрос с АнглоСО: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1270209/1892060.

Comment: Благодарю вас, за ваш полный ответ !